# Inserting Information into a Junction Table ColdFusion

Tags: php, sql, coldfusion

On a Blog post page I add Title, Body, and UserID (Foreign Key from Authors Table) into my BlogPost Table:

```
<!--- Query to Insert Blog --->
<cfquery Result="blogEntry" datasource="prpblog">
    INSERT INTO BlogPosts (Title, BlogBody, UserID)
    VALUES
    (
        <cfqueryparam value='#Form.Title#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"/>,  
        <cfqueryparam value='#Form.BlogBody#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"/>, 
        <cfqueryparam value='#Form.SelectAuthor#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>
    )
</cfquery>
```

Then I want to add which tags the blog consists of into a Junction table (because of the many-to-many relationship caused by tags belonging to multiple blogs/blogs with multiple tags)

I know how to insert the tag into the junction table, but how would I insert my blogID into this table? The BlogID is an autonumber when a new blog is entered.

Junction Table column example:

```
    BlogID  TagID
    10          1
    10          10
    10          13
    9           10
    9           1

<Select name="SelectTag" multiple="multiple" size="6">
<cfoutput QUERY="Tags"><option value="#TagID#">#Tag#</option></cfoutput>
</select>

<cfquery name="AddTag" datasource="prpblog">
    INSERT INTO BlogTagJunction (TagID)
    VALUES
    (
                <cfqueryparam value='#Form.???' cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>
        <cfqueryparam value='#Form.SelectTag#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>
    )
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Since you are allowing multiple selections, you'll have to loop through the values.  Cfdump your form scope to see what your submission looks like.

Comment: FYI, rolled back to previous version because the subsequent answers no longer made sense without the original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I solved the problem myself by making a query statement after the
>   insert statement for the blog that grabs the blog ID from the blog I
>   just created:

That will only work if there is a unique index on the `Title` column. However, it is likely you do not even need a separate query. If `BlogID` is some sort of auto-incrementing column (identity, auto increment, ...), use the [`result` attribute of cfquery](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html) to retrieve the generated ID value from your first `INSERT` statement. The exact syntax is db dependent.

Given that the source of `TagID` is another database table, it is simpler to skip looping and use a `INSERT/SELECT` to generate the junction table records in a single statement. You did not state your DBMS, but for SQL Server something like this. Change the "cfsqltypes" as needed:

```
  <!--- create the blog entry --->
  <cfquery result="blogEntry" ....>
       INSERT INTO BlogPost ( Title, Body, UserID )
       VALUES  
       (
         ... the values here  ....
       )
  </cfquery>

  <!--- associate the new blog entry with the selected tag id's --->
  <cfquery ....>
     INSERT INTO BlogTagJunction (BlogID, TagID)
     SELECT  <cfqueryparam value="#blogEntry.IDENTITYCOL#"  
                        cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
            , TagID
     FROM  YourTagTable
     WHERE TagID  IN
           (
              <cfqueryparam value="#Form.SelectTag#" 
                   list="true" 
                   cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>
           )
  </cfquery>
```

NB: Be sure to wrap both queries in a `cftransaction` to ensure data integrity.

**Update from comments:**

If you are using MS Access, then using the `result` attribute is out. CFQuery does not support that feature for MS Access. So you need to use an alternative method for grabbing the newly created ID.

As discussed in [this link](http://mysecretbase.com/get_the_last_id.cfm) , there are several ways to do that. One of them is adding a UUID column to your table. Another option for MS Access is using the [@@identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230719/scope-identity-in-microsoft-access) variable. After you insert a record into a table with an "Autonumber" column, the @@identity value will contain the ID of the new record. [This blog contains an example](http://cfmxplus.blogspot.com/2002/08/oh-my-select-identity-works-in-access.html). NB: As I noted in your other thread, **you must enclose BOTH queries in cftransaction** or it will not work correctly.

In summary you need to do three things:

1. `INSERT` a new record into the `BlogPost` table
2. Grab the new BlogID you just created
3. Insert the selected tagID's into `BlogTagJunction` using the new id from step #2

Again, with MS Access you cannot skip the `cftransaction` here or it will not work. Putting it all together:

```
<cftransaction>

    <!--- create the blog record --->
    <cfquery result="blogEntry" ....>
        INSERT INTO BlogPost ( Title, Body, UserID )
        VALUES  
        (
        ... the values here  ....
        )
    </cfquery>

    <!--- get the ID of the record you just inserted --->
    <cfquery name="getNewRecord">
        SELECT  @@identity AS TheNewID
    </cfquery>

    <!--- Use that new ID to associate blog and selected tag id's --->
    <cfquery ....>
        INSERT INTO BlogTagJunction (BlogID, TagID)
        SELECT  <cfqueryparam value="#getNewRecord.TheNewID#"  
                    cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
               , TagID
        FROM  YourTagTable
        WHERE TagID  IN
        (
            <cfqueryparam value="#Form.SelectTag#" 
               list="true" 
               cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>
        )
    </cfquery>

</cftransaction>
```

Comment: "Element IDENTITYCOL is undefined in BLOGENTRY."

Comment: As mentioned, it requires an auto-incrementing column and the syntax is db specific. You still did not tell us: 1) What is your DBMS?  2) What is column type of `BlogID` and is it auto-incrementing? 3) Are you using the `result` attribute (NOT query name)?

Comment: Microsoft Access (not by choice). Yes it is also auto-increment. Added what the code looks like on top.

Comment: Then you cannot use the `result` attribute. MS Access is not supported. You might try this older suggestion about [retrieving auto-incrementing values from Access](http://mysecretbase.com/get_the_last_id.cfm). That said.. honestly this is one of the many reasons why using desktop db like Access is not a great idea. (Edit) Even MS recommends against using MS Access in web applications. Better to upgrade to a real DBMS like SQL Server, MySQL etcetera that is specifically designed for multi-threaded apps - and unlike Access - is actually supported.

Comment: This blog is a blog where only a select few people write post, and also will not be posting at the same time. Not many people will actually look at the page either. It is a campus blog. So I do not think anything in the given link you provided seems necessary. Correct me if I'm wrong of course.

Comment: Well using those options (@@identity for Access, uuid, etecetera) are the only way to *guarantee* you get the correct ID every time. If your application *never* has two concurrent users at one time, then it would not be an issue. But web apps are multi-threaded, so it certainly *could* happen and if it did you might end up with the wrong id. Whether you choose to take that risk is up to you. However, those are the only ways to guarantee you *always* get the correct id. Even cflock (which I am not a fan of) does not guarantee it as the data can still be modified outside of CF.

Comment: Without expanding into another separate StackOverFlow question, how would I process every chosen value for my tags. Basically, the Tags are chosen from a List box. I'm aware when multiple values are chosen that they are given delimiters and are listed as such "2,3,4,etc". How do I allow my code to insert each value as its own separate row, and have the same blog ID for each?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself by making a query statement after the insert statement for the blog that grabs the blog ID from the blog I just created:

```
<CFQUERY name="BlogID" datasource="blog">
SELECT BlogID
FROM BlogPosts
WHERE Title = '#Form.Title#'
</CFQUERY>
```

Then I do a CFoutput to output the queried BlogID Value.