# ColdFusion Resolving Many to Many Relationship

Tags: ms-access, coldfusion

This is my submission page to inserting a new post into a blog.

The first Inserts the Title, BlogBody, and UserID into the database.

The second part is meant to insert the Tags the user chooses for the blog, and associates them to the Blog via a Junction Table.
Basically, if a user chooses more than one Tag, then each tag will be a separate entry in the junction table, and will be matched up with the BlogID created in an Auto-Increment Field when the new blog post is inserted.

Currently this code does the blog insert correctly. It also does part 2 correct as long as the same title isn't used twice (because `WHERE Title = '#Form.Title#'`) and I choose only 1 tag.

How can I change this code to allow multiple tags to have multiple entries within the junction table, and also how can I change it to where I get no anomalies where the user gives two blogs the same title.

For the Anomalies portion I've tried `SELECT (Max)BlogID FROM BlogPosts`, however I get a converting from "complex to simple error".

I'm well aware that Microsoft Access is not a good database to use, however this is what I'm forced to use.

```
<cfquery name="AddBlog" datasource="prpblog">
    INSERT INTO BlogPosts (Title, BlogBody, UserID)
    VALUES
    (
        <cfqueryparam value='#Form.Title#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"/>, 
        <cfqueryparam value='#Form.BlogBody#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"/>, 
        <cfqueryparam value='#Form.SelectAuthor#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>
    )
</cfquery>

<!--- Query to find BlogID from newest post --->
<CFQUERY name="BlogID" datasource="prpblog">
SELECT BlogID
FROM BlogPosts
WHERE Title = '#Form.Title#'
</CFQUERY>                      

<!--- Query to Insert BlogID/TagID into Junction Table --->
<cfquery name="AddTag" datasource="prpblog">
    INSERT INTO BlogTagJunction (BlogID,TagID, TagReal)
    VALUES
    (
        <Cfoutput query="BlogID">#BlogID#</cfoutput>,
        <cfqueryparam value='#Form.SelectTag#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" />,
        <cfqueryparam value='#Form.SelectTag#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />


    )
</cfquery>
```

**(Update from deleted answer)**

This is the code I wrote based off the tips from the weblink you provided (ignoring the CF Transaction for now). I receive:

> Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC
>   Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data
>   type mismatch in criteria expression.

I removed the "Select Statement" to help diagnose the problem. I still receive the same error. With just the top statement in the code I changed createUUID() to SubID() and receive:Variable SUBID is undefined, which I expected. I understand now what is suppose to do however.

```
<!--- Query to Insert Blog --->
<cfset variables.SubID=createUUID()>
        <cfquery name="AddBlog" datasource="blog">
            INSERT INTO BlogPosts (
                Title,
                BlogBody,
                UserID,
                SubID
            )
            VALUES (
                <cfqueryparam value='#Form.Title#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"/>,
                <cfqueryparam value='#Form.BlogBody#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"/>,
                <cfqueryparam value='#Form.SelectAuthor#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>,
                '#variables.SubID#'
            )
        </cfquery>
        <cfquery 
   name="getMyID" 
   datasource="blog">
   SELECT 
      BlogPosts.BlogID
   FROM 
      BlogPosts
   WHERE 
      BlogPosts.SubID = '#variables.SubID#'
</cfquery>
```

---

@Leigh

This is the code I wrote based off the tips from the weblink you provided (ignoring the CF Transaction for now)

I receive:
**Error Executing Database Query.
[Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.**

I removed the "Select Statement" to help diagnose the problem. I still receive the same error.
With just the top statement in the code I changed `createUUID()` to `SubID()` and receive:**Variable SUBID is undefined**, which I expected. I understand now what is suppose to do however.

```
<!--- Query to Insert Blog --->
<cfset variables.SubID=createUUID()>
        <cfquery name="AddBlog" datasource="blog">
            INSERT INTO BlogPosts (
                Title,
                BlogBody,
                UserID,
                SubID
            )
            VALUES (
                <cfqueryparam value='#Form.Title#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"/>,
                <cfqueryparam value='#Form.BlogBody#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"/>,
                <cfqueryparam value='#Form.SelectAuthor#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>,
                '#variables.SubID#'
            )
        </cfquery>
        <cfquery 
   name="getMyID" 
   datasource="blog">
   SELECT 
      BlogPosts.BlogID
   FROM 
      BlogPosts
   WHERE 
      BlogPosts.SubID = '#variables.SubID#'
</cfquery>
```

**EDIT:**
This is what I interpreted from the other post: I end up with a 
`Invalid data @@Identity for CFSQLTYPE CF_SQL_INTEGER.` error.

`<cfquery name="AddTag" datasource="prpblog">
            INSERT INTO BlogTagJunction (BlogID, TagID)
            SELECT <cfqueryparam value="@@Identity as Key" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">,
            TagID
            FROM Tags
            WHERE TagID IN
                (
                <cfqueryparam value="#Form.SelectTag#" 
                   list="true" 
                   cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>
                   )
        </cfquery>`

Comment: I recommend re-reading [your other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465173/inserting-information-into-a-junction-table-cold-fusion) and the referenced link. It explains how to do it A) Obtain the new id using MS Access' @@IDENTITY - NB: The statements must be enclosed in a `cftransaction`. B) Use the INSERT/SELECT construct, combined with <cfqueryparam list="true"...> to retrieve and insert the selected tags. Side note, no need to use cfoutput within your cfquery. Simple `#variables#` are evaluated automatically. Try it first and post back if you have specific questions.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT Max(BlogID)` ?

Comment: *SELECT Max(BlogID)* Do not use the `max` approach in a web app. It is **not thread safe**

Comment: Was unable to determine how I'd code that with my database using the link provided.

Comment: Post what you tried and we can go from there. Your other thread explains how to insert multiple tag id's, using `result` attribute to get the new id. Since the latter is not supported, you just need to substitute MS Access' `@@identity` value instead. A very brief search for "ColdFusion MS Access @@identity" returns [this thread](http://cfmxplus.blogspot.com/2002/08/oh-my-select-identity-works-in-access.html) which shows exactly how to do it (cont'd)

Comment: All you have to do is plug it into your code. Give it whirl and post back with any problems. Rather than someone just writing the code for you, it is better to try and understand the process for yourself. Then get help with minor syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

From the other thread:

> "I solved the problem myself by making a query statement after the insert statement for the blog that grabs the blog ID from the blog I just created."

In the accepted answer, the user used CFQUERY's built in variable "IDENTITYCOL" to get the value of the new ID. You can't do that with MS Access. Instead you need 3 queries inside a single transaction:

```
<cftransaction action="begin">

    <cftry>

        <cfquery name="AddBlog" datasource="prpblog">
            INSERT INTO BlogPosts (
                Title,
                BlogBody,
                UserID
            )
            VALUES (
                <cfqueryparam value='#Form.Title#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"/>,
                <cfqueryparam value='#Form.BlogBody#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"/>,
                <cfqueryparam value='#Form.SelectAuthor#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>
            )
        </cfquery>

        <!--- Query to find BlogID from newest post --->
        <cfquery name="BlogID" datasource="prpblog">
            SELECT @@IDENTITY AS NEW_ID
        </cfquery>

        <!--- Query to Insert BlogID/TagID into Junction Table --->
        <cfquery name="AddTag" datasource="prpblog">
            INSERT INTO BlogTagJunction (
                BlogID,
                TagID, 
                TagReal
            )
            VALUES (
                <cfqueryparam value='#BlogID.NEW_ID#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" />,
                <cfqueryparam value='#Form.SelectTag#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" />,
                <cfqueryparam value='#Form.SelectTag#' cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
            )
        </cfquery>

    <cfcatch type="database">

        <cftransaction action="rollback">

    </cfcatch>

    </cftry>

    <cftransaction action="commit">

</cftransaction>
```

Hope this helps.

UPDATE: [Here's why you should not use SELECT MAX(ID) to get a newly inserted ID.](http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/6/1/please-stop-using-select-max-id)

Comment: I thought database exception is automatically rolledback inside a `cftransaction`?

Comment: Not always. If your database is configured to automatically commit a transaction, then maybe. Otherwise, when an error occurs the transaction stays open until you explicitly close it or roll it back. If this happens, your database will slow to a crawl as more and more transactions are left open (which chews up resources). I unfortunately discovered that one day when a company's Dev DB did auto-commit, but their Production DB did not. I always find it best to define BEGIN, ROLLBACK and COMMIT with a TRY/CATCH statement. I've updated the code with the COMMIT.

Comment: The try tag wasn't enclosed around the catch so it popped an error. I placed the try in the correct spot and now I get "Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values." error, similar to when I tried Select Max(BlogID). I will continue to look at this, as my progress has been at a halt for a couple days.

Comment: We need to see the code you are using. Can you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22491585/104223) and append your current code and the error message?

Comment: Don't use SELECT MAX() in this case. It will ultimately fail you.